# bash script to eliminate duplicate elements

Tags: bash, shell

I have a two-column text file

```
Gene Description
AAA1  description_1
BBB1  description_2
BBB1  description_2_a
CCC1  description_3
...
```

I want a file that has only unique entries in the "Gene" column even if the description column is different. Example output

```
Gene Description
AAA1 description_1
BBB1 description_2
CCC1 description_3
...
```

I tried:

```
cut -f 1 file.txt | sort -u > output.txt
```

but `output.txt` has only the *Gene* column but not the *Description* column. Can you suggest edits?

Comment: Try `uniq --check-chars=4 file.txt`.

Comment: Oh, another duplicate duplicate question